# Flask - make `abort` use plain text

Tags: python, http, flask, error-handling, http-error

I am using Flask's `abort` function in my API methods to prematurely stop execution and return an error:

```py
abort(404, errMsg)
```

This returns `errMsg` inside a preformatted HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>(errMsg)</p>
```

However, since I am building an API, not a webpage, I want the error to be returned as plain text instead. I have seen the docs page on [custom error pages](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/), but I'd rather redefine `abort` **once** for every error, rather than having to define it for each error code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redefining internal `werkzeug` classes, you can instead provide a `Response` object to `abort`:

```py
from flask import abort as fabort

def abort(status_code, message):
    response = make_response(f'{status_code}\n{message}')
    response.status_code = status_code
    fabort(response)
```

Comment: neat, btw, you may want to set some default value to `message`, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.get_body` (the method used to get that formatted HTML) to your own `get_body` function and return the plain text.
And it is still easy to change the error message for users.

```py
from flask import Flask, abort
import werkzeug.exceptions


def get_body(self, environ=None, scope=None):
    return f'{self.code}, {self.name}, {self.description or ""}'


werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.get_body = get_body

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    abort(404)


@app.route('/nothome')
def not_home():
    abort(500, 'some server error happened')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that I still want to be able to set different error messages each time I call `abort`. I just want these messages to be plain text rather than preformatted HTML.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett updated once again, forgot to remove tags from what `.get_description` returns

Comment: you also want to redefine `.get_description` to remove HTML escaping and `<br>` tags. I've edited your answer. There is also a problem that double quote characters in `errMsg` are escaped to `&quot;` - do you know how to stop this from happening?

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett I think there is no need to redefine `.get_description`, just not use it at all. the `{self.description or ""}` already converts to string if it is not a string and if it is `None` it will use the empty quotes, now it should really be just plain text